# Issues continuing a dialog created proactively

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have been able to start a dialog proactively with an adaptive card using the code below.

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("proactivetest")]
    public async Task ProactiveTest()
    {
        try
        {
            await _frameworkAdapter.CreateConversationAsync(
                TeamsChannelId,
                ServiceUrl,
                new MicrosoftAppCredentials(MicrosoftAppId, MicrosoftAppPassword),
                new ConversationParameters(true, null, null, string.Empty,
                    new Activity(
                        type: ActivityTypes.Message,
                        text: "test",
                        serviceUrl: ServiceUrl,
                        channelId: TeamsChannelId
                        ),
                    new Dictionary<string, string> { ["teamsChannelId"] = TeamsChannelId }),
                Callback, default);
        }
        catch(Exception Ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {Ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    public async Task Callback(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        DialogContext dialogContext = await _DialogSet.CreateContextAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);

        await dialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(AdaptiveCardTests), null, cancellationToken);

        await _Accessors.ConversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);

        return;
    }
```

But when replying with values in the adaptive card I am unable to continue the dialog. I have tried to Create a DialogContext from the DialogSet but it always returns DialogContext["null"] and then runs a new dialog.

```
        protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        DialogContext dialogContext = await _DialogSet.CreateContextAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);

        if (dialogContext.ActiveDialog != null)   
        {
            await dialogContext.ContinueDialogAsync(cancellationToken);
            return;
        }

        _Logger.LogInformation("Running dialog with Message Activity.");
        await dialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(AdaptiveCardTests), null, cancellationToken);
    }
```

If you then reply to this new dialog the above code works correctly and continues the dialog as expected.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to solve this problem, the channelId parameter on BotFrameworkAdapter.CreateConversationAsync() need to be set to "msteams" and not the Teams Channel Id which I originally had this set to.

Below is the updated code that was working correctly.

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("proactivetest")]
    public async Task ProactiveTest()
    {
        try
        {
            await _frameworkAdapter.CreateConversationAsync(
                "msteams",
                ServiceUrl,
                new MicrosoftAppCredentials(MicrosoftAppId, MicrosoftAppPassword),
                new ConversationParameters(true, new ChannelAccount($"28:{MicrosoftAppId}", BotName, null, null), null, string.Empty,
                    new Activity(
                        type: ActivityTypes.Message,
                        text: "test",
                        serviceUrl: ServiceUrl,
                        channelId: "msteams"
                        ),
                    new Dictionary<string, string> { ["teamsChannelId"] = TeamsChannelId }),ProactiveCallback, default);
        }
        catch(Exception Ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {Ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    public async Task ProactiveCallback(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        DialogContext dialogContext = await _DialogSet.CreateContextAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);

        await dialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(AdaptiveCardTests), null, cancellationToken);

        await _Accessors.ConversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please see this document for [Send proactive notifications to users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp). Also have a look into the [C# sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages) code for proactive message

Comment: I have looked taken a look the BotBuilder-Samples and I am able to achieve sending an Activity proactively fine.

My question was about having issues continuing a Dialog after starting one proactively.

Thanks,